# Cassandra select by timeuuid

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, timeuuid

Spring-boot-data-cassandra

CQL:

```
CREATE TABLE device_data (
    device_id uuid,
    time timeuuid,
    unit text,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY (device_id, time)
)
```

Repository:

```
public interface DeviceDataRepository extends CassandraRepository<DeviceData> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM device_data WHERE device_id = ?0 AND time > ?1")
    List<DeviceData> findByDeviceIdAndTime(UUID deviceId, Date from);
}
```

Usage:

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1);
    List<DeviceData> pump1Data = deviceDataService.findByDeviceIdAndFrom(UUID.fromString(pumpid), calendar.getTime());
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Invalid INTEGER constant (633826800000) for "time" of type timeuuid; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid INTEGER constant (633826800000) for "time" of type timeuuid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM device_data WHERE device_id = ?0 AND time > ?1")
List<DeviceData> findByDeviceIdAndTime(UUID deviceId, UUID from);
```

DeviceData:

```
...
private UUID time;
...
```

Controller:

```
    List<DeviceData> pumpData = deviceDataService.findByDeviceIdAndFrom(UUID.fromString(id), calendar.getTime());
```